# XSL Replace Namespace

Tags: xslt

I have below XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:OrderChange ns0:transactionPurposeIndicator="Change" xmlns:ns0="http://www.api.org/pidXML">
<ns0:OrderChangeProperties>
<ns0:OrderChangeNumber>1</ns0:OrderChangeNumber>
<ns0:OrderChangeDate>2009-10-19</ns0:OrderChangeDate>
</ns0:OrderChangeProperties>
</ns0:OrderChange>
```

And i need to convert this to below format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pidx:OrderChange pidx:transactionPurposeIndicator="Change"    xmlns:pidx="http://www.api.org/pidXML" xmlns="http://www.api.org/pidXML" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.api.org/pidXML Z:\integration\trunk\schemas\pidx\OrderChange_1-2.xsd">
<pidx:OrderChangeProperties>
<pidx:OrderChangeNumber>1</pidx:OrderChangeNumber>
<pidx:OrderChangeDate>2009-10-19</pidx:OrderChangeDate>
</pidx:OrderChangeProperties>
</pidx:OrderChange>
```

Can someone please let me know the XSL which would do this transformation.
I have tried several XSL tranformations but not able to achieve it.
Really appreciate all the help

Thanks

Comment: Contrary to the title, you are not actually asking to replace the namespace - only to change the prefix that stands for the existing namespace. Why is this necessary at all? The change is purely cosmetic.

Comment: Hey Michael, We are working with a Cloud based application and their requirements are pretty stringent. They need the XML specifically in the format i mentioned above. Also, if you check the <OrderChange> tag in the to-be format (second code) it has several more "namespaces" defined than in as-is (first code) so i assumed i would need "namespace replacement" as well Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We are working with a Cloud based application and their requirements
>   are pretty stringent. They need the XML specifically in the format i
>   mentioned above.

Well, it should make no difference whatsoever. If it does, then "they" are doing it wrong.

> Also, if you check the  tag in the to-be
>   format (second code) it has several more "namespaces" defined than in
>   as-is (first code) so i assumed i would need "namespace replacement"
>   as well

Adding these is relatively trivial, and has nothing to do with changing the namespace prefix. Anyway, try the following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns0="http://www.api.org/pidXML"
xmlns:pidx="http://www.api.org/pidXML"
exclude-result-prefixes="ns0"> 
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="ns0:OrderChange">
    <pidx:OrderChange xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.api.org/pidXML Z:\integration\trunk\schemas\pidx\OrderChange_1-2.xsd">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </pidx:OrderChange>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="pidx:{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
<xsl:attribute name="pidx:{local-name()}">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. I will check with them.I tried your code and it "almost" works perfect. I get <pidx:OrderChange pidx:transactionPurposeIndicator="Change" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.api.org/pidXML Z:\integration\trunk\schemas\pidx\OrderChange_1-2.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:pidx="http://www.api.org/pidXML">. This is slightly different from what i need. Could you please help me out a little bit more please. I have tried to play around with XSL but unable to get the exact structure they need. Appreciate all the help and suggestions

Comment: @user2157477 If you mean the internal order of attributes, that's truly without any significance and any attempt to control it is a waste of time and effort.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Michael. Actually there is supposed to be a xmlns="http://www.api.org/pidXML in the to-be XML which is not coming in. I tried to add it in XSL but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: @user2157477 Which processor are you using? As an aside, if an element has a prefix, and the prefix is bound to a given namespace, then the element is already in the given namespace. Adding an explicit namespace declaration within the element's tag is redundant (thus potentially conflicting), and some processors will remove the attempt to do so. IOW, this is just yet another exercise in futility. Perhaps you should seek clarifications from the people responsible for the target application, before you try so diligently to follow their misguided guidelines?

Comment: Thanks Michael, I am using the XSL in SAP. I will check with them.

Comment: Hey Michael, So it seems like the XML your XSL is generating is working great for them :) One thing they have requested is to remove the pidx prefix from the attributes (only have that prefix for the element). I have tried to play around with the xsl but unable to achieve it. Could you please let me know how it can be achieved

Comment: I guess i just answered myself :). Below is the change i did and it is not adding pidx prefix to attributes: <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:attribute>

Answer (score 1):

If the cloud based application insists on using particular namespace prefixes then you should ask some serious questions about the competence of the people running this service. That's really bad XML practice.

Officially, XSLT 1.0 gives you no control over the choice of namespace prefix in the output. It's not supposed to matter, so the spec lets implementations do what they like. In practice, however, in nearly all practical cases actual implementations will use the prefix you specify in the stylesheet; and in XSLT 2.0 this has become mandatory. So the solution from @michael.hor257k using

```
<xsl:element name="pidx:{local-name()}">
```

should do the trick in practice, even though it's not guaranteed.